# Prevent application from changing the window layer

Tags: x11, xorg, fluxbox

I'm running Debian 10 with fluxbox.

I have an application where the window layer keeps changing to "Above dock", despite me checking "Remember..." "Layer". This layer change seems to happen randomly.

How do I prevent this from happening? Pop ups created by the application launch with the "Normal" layer, so they are unclickable until I find them...certainly a very annoying issue.

This *only* happens with this one application.

Two more questions as asides:

Do other window managers have this layer feature, or is it only fluxbox?

What can control the window layer? Is it the window manager only, the application only, or both the window manager and application?

Comment: I did and i hated it. But since Mate Desktop im on GNome2/Mate. No idesk conf files for desktop icons etc etc. I'm still missing the two windows in one functionality. Anyway, can't remember which program it was. Somethign desktopish like Pidgin or whatever. The minimalist system struggle is real. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a static configuration! Create the following in your `apps` conf file:

```
[group]
  [app] (distinct_name)
  [Layer] {8}
[end]
```

Whereas the numbers correlate to:

- 2 - AboveDock
- 4 - Dock
- 6 - Top
- 8 - Normal
- 10 - Bottom
- 12 - Desktop

Create the shortcut for your app with:

```
command --name distinct_name
```

This way you can add several confs for one command. Remaining options would be:

```
[Hidden|IconHidden|FocusHidden] {yes|no}
```

If your command doesnt support the `-name` parameter, lookup its name with `xprop`.

Please read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060170/xdotool-what-are-class-and-classname-for-a-window)